# Problem with a never ending recursive function in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I am trying to write the following function:

```
create_APIds( PId, ASA, APIds ) 
ASA: List of type [a01-1, a02-2, a03-1]
PId: an int like 1 for example
APIds: returning list of all the a0s of ASA, which are linked to PId
```

For example, when calling `create_APIds(1, [a01-1, a02-1, a03-2], APIds).` it should return `APIds = [a01, a02]`.

I have tried the following, but my implementation does not stop and I cant understand why:

```
create_APIds( PId, [], _ ).
create_APIds( PId,[AId-Pid|ASA], APIds ) :-
    Pid is PId, 
    append( APIds, [AId], APIds2   ),
    create_APIds( PId, ASA, APIds2 ).
```

Comment: Prolog doesn't have functions - it has predicates.

Comment: It looks like your implementation does stop with a `fail`. It's not recursing infinitely.

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0):

Your function can proceed when `PId` is the same as `Pid`. But what happens when it's not? The function fails, which means it then looks for a way to try again. (And it shouldn't -- it should just not include that item.) `append` is pretty flexible on finding new ways to join things, which turns out to be a bad idea in this case. (It's also called wrong, but we'll get to that.)

So a partial fix is to handle when PId isn't Pid: `(Pid is PId -> append( APIds, [AId], APIds2); APIds2 = APIds)`. (Which you can read as "If `Pid` is `PId`, then do the `append`; else do the `=`.) This lets the function keep going wehter the `AId` fits your `PId` or not. But this still has a problem that although you're accumulating `AId`'s as you go into the recursive calls, they're not returned. Let's make that simpler. We'll let the recursive call collect `AId`'s from the rest of the list it works on, and stick the current `AID` (if any) on the result.

```
create_APIds( _PId, [], []). %Whatever PId is, there are 0 copies of it in empty list!

create_APIds( PId,[AId-Pid|ASA], APIds ) :-
    create_APIds( PId, ASA, APIds2),  %Process the rest of the list
    (Pid = PId -> 
     append([AId], APIds2, APIds   ); %If appropriate, prepend this AId
     APIds = APIds2).                 %else don't.
```

While we're at it, let's replace `is` with `=`: `is` is used when you want to do calculation, but you're not here.

There's also an easier way to write that append: `APIds=[AId|APIds2]`.

Answer (score -1):

Can use built-in predicate `bagof`:

```
create_apids(P, L, As) :-
    bagof(A, member(A-P, L), As).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- create_apids(1, [a01-1, a02-1, a03-2], APIds).
APIds = [a01, a02].
```

I think it's better for predicate names to be all lower-case, to prevent confusion with variables.

Answer (score -1):

Just like in any other programming language ecosystem, there are idiomatic ways to achieve your goal. Which one to use depends on the larger context and your constraints.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75970156/14411997) jumps straight to one of the options, missing an important intermediate step. If you used member/2 without the bagof/3, you will get the solutions on backtracking instead of in a list; in many cases, this is what you *really* need:

```
?- member(X-1, [a01-1, a02-2, a03-1]).
X = a01 ;
X = a03.
```

You can collect this to a list but you are disabling backtracking, which is an alternative to lazy evaluation as known from functional languages.

Another option is somehow outlined in the other answers. However, if you would be writing code and not just exercising, you wouldn't do it like that, you'd use a meta-predicate, for example include/3:

```
has_pid(PID, _-PID).
```

and then:

```
?- include(has_pid(1), [a01-1, a02-2, a03-1], R0),
   pairs_keys(R0, R).
R0 = [a01-1, a03-1],
R = [a01, a03].
```

Please note that the implementation of include/3, as for example in SWI-Prolog, [here](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/56b6020004e42510e3bed27880ae32c54ab262fd/library/apply.pl#L100-L118), is basically the exact same thing as what you are doing in your question, just done correctly.

Homework: is it possible to use convlist/3 instead of include/3 followed by pairs_keys/2?

Comment: "returning list" is in the OP's spec.

Comment: @brebs Yes. What is not in OP's spec is anything else at all :-) either way, findall/bagof/setof are full of surprises both in semantics and performance. I wouldn't _recommend_ them for "list comprehensions" (Python style), this is what maplist/scanlist/include and so on are meant for. But please be my guest and jump on the "everyone else is obviously a moron" train, it is so much fun.

Comment: Let's be conscious that OP is a beginner and had multiple problems in his code. This suggests that the best fix *for him* is to -- as he said -- understand what's wrong with his code, so he can become a better programmer.

Comment: @TopologicalSort :D You are making two _very_ bold claims here; 1. You can tell what a good programmer feels like (and what code they would write, I assume?) and 2. That you know how to take a not yet good programmer and make them better by showing them code.

Answer (score -2):

```prolog
create_APIds( _, [], [] ).
create_APIds( PId, [AId-PId|ASA], [AId|Rest] ) :-
    create_APIds( PId, ASA, Rest ).
create_APIds( PId, [AId-PId2|ASA], APIds ) :-
    not(PId = PId2),
    create_APIds( PId, ASA, APIds ).
```

Running it on your example:

```
?- create_APIds(1, [a01-1, a02-1, a03-2], APIds).
APIds = [a01, a02] ;
false.
```

Comment: I like the look of the code, but you haven't shown that it works and you haven't given any explanation to the OP as to why their code didn't work. The explanation is the only thing that the OP asked for.

Comment: not quite, right? He asked "my implementation does not stop and I cant understand why". But you are right, adding an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: "The answer is correct and working." But is it useful? :-D this tag is a battlefield, please continue answering, the more the merrier

Comment: How do we know that it "is correct and working"? As it stands it's just a code dump. You also agreed that an explanation would be helpful, yet none has been added. This answer is not useful unless someone bothers to copy, paste, and run your code. Who's going to do that? You need to show that it's right and why it answers the OP's question.